# Hide a header from being displayed in Swagger Swashbuckle

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

As I already have a common authorization added how do I remove separate(authorization header) from each and every API as shown in the image link below?

[swaggerHub_Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1qlq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

You can simply create a custom attibute and an operation filter inhering from Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.IOperationFilter in order to hide the header from being displayed in swagger.json

```
public class OpenApiHeaderIgnoreAttribute : System.Attribute
{
}
```

class name should end with the name of the base class.

```
public class OpenApiHeaderIgnoreFilter : Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiOperation operation, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation == null || context == null || context.ApiDescription?.ParameterDescriptions == null)
            return;

        var parametersToHide = context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions
            .Where(parameterDescription => ParameterHasIgnoreAttribute(parameterDescription))
            .ToList();

        if (parametersToHide.Count == 0)
            return;

        foreach (var parameterToHide in parametersToHide)
        {
            var parameter = operation.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(parameter => string.Equals(parameter.Name, parameterToHide.Name, System.StringComparison.Ordinal));
            if (parameter != null)
                operation.Parameters.Remove(parameter);
        }
    }

    private static bool ParameterHasIgnoreAttribute(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.ApiParameterDescription parameterDescription)
    {
        if (parameterDescription.ModelMetadata is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadata metadata)
        {
            return metadata.Attributes.ParameterAttributes.Any(attribute => attribute.GetType() == typeof(OpenApiHeaderIgnoreAttribute));
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and set this filter class in your startup class configureServices method as below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.OperationFilter<OpenApiHeaderIgnoreFilter>();
    }
}
```

and also update your API method in controller as below:

```
[EnableQuery]
[SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "Odata" })]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([OpenApiHeaderIgnore] [FromHeader(Name = ClaimNames.AccessToken)] string token)
{
// code
}
```